# Как кастовать list entity в инетерфейс?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Подскажите пожалуйста как преобразовать коллекцию:

Несколько entity хочу объединить при поищи интерфейса EntityUnion

```
public interface EntityUnion {
}
```

Есть entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advantageous_tickets")
public class Table implements EntityUnion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
```

Репозиторий для извлечения entity Table

```
public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<Table, Long> {
}
```

Далее Dto

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DTo {
    private Iterable<EntityUnion> entityUnion;
}
```

У нас есть какой-то сервис

```
Iterable<Table> table =  tableRepository.findAll();
Dto.builder()
.entityUnion(???)
.build()
```

Как table добавить в entityUnion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java обобщенные типы инвариантны. Перед тем, как добавить `Iterable<Table> table` в `dto`, необходимо привести шаблонный тип, например, так:

```java
List<EntityUnion> table =  tableRepository
                             .findAll()
                             .stream()
                             .map(t -> (EntityUnion)t)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```